# How do I integrate Vision API for barcode with google cardboard?

Tags: java, android, barcode, barcode-scanner, google-cardboard

I am trying to integrate a qr code scanner into my google cardboard program. I have used the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28661929/5553498) to start a cardboard camera. I am encountering problems when I try to integrate the vision API for barcode reader into this. I need to start camera passing a texture to the vision API's camerasource portion.

```
final CameraSource cameraSource = new CameraSource
            .Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
            .build();
```

How do I integrate the qr code scanner with vision API into my cardboard app?

Answer (score 0):

Google has provided a supremely useful View for managing your `CameraSource` for preview and detection.  You don't have to worry about managing the texture itself or determining the layout of the texture/surface in your view.

It's called `CameraSourcePreview`, and it's used to manage the operation of your `CameraSource` along with a `SurfaceView`.

You can use the `CameraSourcePreview` like any other view in your layout, for example in this full screen `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">

  <com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview
      android:id="@+id/preview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">   
  </com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in your activity you set up your `BarcodeDetector` and `CameraSource` like normal (*probably in your `onCreate()` method*) and then (*likely `onResume()`*) start your `CameraSourcePreview`.  It would look something like this:

```
if (mCameraSource != null) {
   try {
       mPreview.start(mCameraSource, mGraphicOverlay);
   } catch (IOException e) {
       Log.e(TAG, "Unable to start camera source.", e);
       mCameraSource.release();
       mCameraSource = null;
   }
}
```

So really, you'll just be managing your `CameraSource` through your the `CameraSourcePreview`, but it handles a lot of the heavy lifting of the layout/preview/etc. so you don't have to.  Check out the [`BarcodeCaptureActivity`](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/BarcodeCaptureActivity.java) to see more about how the activity manages these components.

Check out the [barcode-reader](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader) sample in the [android vision sample projects](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision) for the complete project sample.

Hope that helps, cheers.